# How do Human Skin Creases Vary?

Tags: human-anatomy, skin

I am studying human gross anatomy in order to produce an anatomically correct CGI model of the human body. As part of this, I'm attempting to understand the different features that define the topography of the skin. One class of features is the creasing of the skin, which appears to manifest both on a large and small scale (illustrated in figure 1 of [2]) with variation about the body. In my reading, I have found [1] which catalogues the major creases and only [2] which briefly discusses the smaller creases and cites paywalled articles. Since this topic seems particularly obscure, it would be good to have a definitive summary of this topic. Therefore:

1. What are the different types of skin creases?
2. Is there terminology that distinguishes the larger and smaller creases?
3. How are they distributed about the body?

[1]: Mallouris, Andreas & Yiacoumettis, Andreas & Thomaidis, Vasilios & Karayiannakis, Anastasios & Simopoulos, Constantinos & Kakagia, Despoina & Tsaroucha, Alexandra. (2012). A record of skin creases and folds. European Journal of Plastic Surgery. 10.1007/s00238-012-0774-3.

[2]: Wong, R., Geyer, S., Weninger, W., Guimberteau, J.‐C. and Wong, J.K. (2016), The dynamic anatomy and patterning of skin. Exp Dermatol, 25: 92-98. doi:10.1111/exd.12832